# Complexity of multiplication

Tags: complexity-theory, arithmetic

I've been reading around the area of complexity and arithmetic operations using logic gates; one thing that is confusing me is that 
\begin{equation}
\Theta (n^{2})
\end{equation}
is quoted as being the complexity for multiplication for iterative adition. But addition of a number requires \begin{equation}
log_2(n)
\end{equation}
operations, 1 for each bit or 8 times that for each nand gate involved in doing this. So it strikes me as obvious that adding that number n times will have a complexity of 
\begin{equation}
n \log_2(n)
\end{equation}
Which is definitely less than 
\begin{equation}
\Theta (n^{2})
\end{equation}
So where is this additional factor of
\begin{equation}
\frac{n}{\log_2(n)}
\end{equation}
coming from?

Comment: Check which model of computation is assumed, and what $n$ denotes exactly.

Comment: @Raphael +1 Good advice. When working with numbers, this is very a common detail to get mixed up.

Comment: Nobody sane would calculate $a \times b$ by adding $a$ together $b$ times. There are far more efficient [multiplication algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm), some of which you should've learned in grade school.

Comment: I am aware that this is far from how multiplication is executed in modern computors. I was just confused at the compexity given for this method. I am curious though which methods should I have been taught for multiplication? I'm not sure I can recall any. I read your link and do recall learning long multiplication (not really something that needs teaching, very intuitive), but that isn't any more efficient for a computor.

Comment: Ah yes, I see how the "shift and add" method is alot faster than iterative adition. Not so easy to understand its implimentation at a bit level though.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but to multiply two n bit numbers using shift and add is complexity n!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Addition of a number of size $n$ takes time $O(n)$. Don't confuse a number and its encoding size, which is logarithmically smaller.

When multiplying an $n$-bit integer $a$ by an $n$-bit integer $b$ using the iterative addition algorithm, you are adding up to $n$ shifted copies of $a$. Each addition costs you $O(n)$ rather than $O(\log n)$. The numbers $a,b$ itself could be as large as $2^n$.

Comment: Thanks. So for n-bit times a the complexity is a*n?

Comment: Yes, that's right.